# Store Date as mm-dd-yyyy in mysql

Tags: mysql, date

I am trying to store the date in mysql as `mm-dd-yyyy`.
The following query updates the table stores the date as `0000-00-00`

```
UPDATE  `h3`.`newbatch` SET  `DateCreated` =  '11-08-2013' WHERE 
 `newbatch`.`BatchID` = 
1 AND  `newbatch`.`DateCreated` =  '2013-11-08' LIMIT 1
```

I can always use `DATE_FORMAT(`DateCreated`,'%m %d %Y')` during `select` but is there a way to store date in that format. 
The datatype of DateCreated is `Date`. 
I am using MySQL.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Do not** modify the storage format of a date. The format for the `date` data type is ISO 8601 standard for a reason. You will lose the ability to perform most date functions elegantly (without first converting to the standard date format). You do the formatting when you run a query.

Comment: This should pop up whenever a question is tagged mysql and date

Comment: @JohnConde or something [like this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178367/help-the-helpless-with-how-to-ask-tag-tips)